# Table of contents in Latex

Tags: latex

I am having trouble in making table of contents using `\tableofcontents` command.Here is my long latex file.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section*{\Huge Chapter 1}
    \section*{\Large Symmetries in Classical Physics} 
    \subsection*{Introduction}
    Symmetries plays an important role in the fields of phsyics.
    \subsection{Mechanics of many particle System}
    Let us consider a system of more than 2 particles such that
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The external forces applied on the particles be say $F^{(ext)}_{i}$ and
    \item Forces applied by the system i.e. the interaction force be $F^{j}_{i}$
        \end{itemize}
    $\therefore$ From Newtons 2nd Law of motion, we can write\\
    \begin{equation}
    m_ia_i=\dot{p_i}=F^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}, i=1,2,...N
    \end{equation}
    Where 'i' stands for denoting the particle and\\
    $F_{i}^{ext}$ stands for  external force acting on $i^{th}$ particle and\\
    $F^{j}_{i}$ is the interaction force acting on the $i^{th}$ particle due to all other paricle (i.e j particle).\\
    So $\therefore$ for N particles one can write it as \\
    \begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i \ne j}^{N}F^{j}_{i} ,where F_{i}^{i}=0.\end{equation*}
From Newtons 3rd law,one can write forces due to internal/interaction force as\\
\begin{equation}
F_{i}^{j}=-F_{j}^{i}.
\end{equation}
\section*{\large \boldmath Important points to be noted:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Interacyion force is only possible iff there are more than on particles and bheave as an central force.
    \item Ad they occur in pair, forces among themselves are neglected.
\end{itemize}
For a closed system,where one knows that linear momentum is conserved i.e.external force acting on the system is zero.\\
$\implies$ A closed system can be reffered to as a inertial frame.\\
$\therefore$ From eq.(1) we have,\\
\begin{equation*}
\sum_i\dot{p_i}=\frac{d^2}{ dt^2}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\sum_iF^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\sum_{i}F_{i}^{ext}  
\end{equation*} where we have used eqn.(2).
\newpage
This is because \\
    As \begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}=\sum_{i \ne j}F^{i}_{j}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
    =\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{i}_{j}]=0 \text{(used dummy variable conncept)}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\implies\sum_{i}\dot{p_i} =  F^{(ext)}_{i}
    \end{equation}
To understand the physical significance of eqn.(1),using the concept of center of mass for many particles we have,\\
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}
    \boldmath {R}=\frac{\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}}{\sum_{i}m_{i}} 
        \end{equation}
        \end{center}
where M=$\sum_{i} m_{i}$ is the total mass of the system.\\
$\therefore$ eqn.(3) become,\\
\begin{equation}
M\frac{d^2R}{dt^2} = \sum_{i}F_{i}^{ext}=F^{ext}
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation*}\textbf{P}=\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=M\dot{\textbf{R}}
\end{equation*}
\section*{Conservation Laws}
\subsection{Linear momentum}
Frome eqn.(5) we have\\
\begin{equation*}\textbf{P}=\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=M\dot{\textbf{R}}
\end{equation*}
\textbf{Important points}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Applying the external force on the entire mass of the system, the C.O.M move along too.
    \item If $F^{ext}$=0,then the total linear momentum is conserved.\\
    i.e $\frac{d\textbf{P}}{dt}$=0 $\implies$ $\textbf{P}$=constant of motion.\\
    $\implies$ C.O.M moves with cobstant/uniform velocity without the extrnal force.\\ 
\end{itemize}
We can relate this scenario by the radioactive decay nucleus disintegrating ejects different particles which move in different direction in such a way that C.O.M moves along with constant velocity after disnitegration.\\
\subsection{Conservation of angular momentum}
Angular momentum for the system of particles is written as:-\\
\begin{equation*}
    \textbf{L}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times p_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=\sum_{i}(r_{i} \times \dot{p_{i}}+\dot{r_{i}} \times p_{i})
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times \dot{p_{i}}  (\because \dot{r_{i}} \times p_{i}=0)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=r_{i} \times(\sum_{i}F^(ext)_i)+\sum_{i \ne j} F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\dot{L}}{dt}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times F^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}r_{i} \times F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation}
where 1st term represnts total torque due to external forces and 2nd term represents total torque due to internal forces.\\
Now one can easily prove that 2nd term in eqn.(6) is zero.\\
\textbf{Proof}:-Let $N_{i}$ be the sum of all internal torque acting on the system i.e.,\\
\begin{equation*} N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} \text{()used dummy varialble concept} \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
N_{i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i \ne j} [ r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}+ r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j}]
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Now as}  F_{i}^{j}= -F_{j}^{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
N_{i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i \ne j}  (r_{i}-r_{j}) \times F_{i}^{j}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
r_{ij}=r_{i}-r_{j}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\implies N_{int}=\frac{1}{2} \times r_{ij} \times F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
From the figure below one can see that $r_{ij} \times F^{j}_{i}$=0; $\because$ $r_{ij}$ of particle $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ are parallel to the line of action of $F^{j}_{i}$.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{IMG_20200426_202229}
    \caption*{Representation of $i_{th}$ and $j_{th}$ particles }
    \label{fig:img20200426202229}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation*}
\implies\bf{ \frac{dL}{dt}=\sum_{i} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{ext}=N^{ext}}=\text{Sum of external torques}
\end{equation*}
Now if $N^{ext}$=0 $\implies$ \text{\textbf{'L'} is aconstant of motion and thus angular momentum is conserved}.
\subsection{Conservation of Energy} 



    \end{document}
```

As far i know the section command automatically adds the title in table of contents but where as for `\section*{}` i saw it doesn't include those and also as i made section in many pages making it bold and large in the table of content also it goes big but i want that to manually make it modify.Anyone on this can help (and also when i preview it in pdf i see my whole written text and like centered and doesn't consume whole page).

Comment: You shouldn't add manual formatting instructions to your `\section*` macros. That goes against the idea of latex to separate content from formatting.  If you want titles of different hierarchy, the easiest approach would be to  choose a documentclass that supports `\chapter` and then use `\chapter`, `\section`,  `\subsection` etc. If you need to modify how the output looks like, have a look at packages like `titlesec` to make these changes consistent for the whole document.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: don't use two letter font commands like `\bf``,  they are obsolete. Also please don't use the floating specifier `[H]`, this is basically a guarantee for suboptimal placement of your floats. Better use `[htbp]` to let tex find the best place

Comment: Never misuse `\\ ` for line breaks outside of tables. If you want to start a new paragraph, simply leave an empty line

Comment: With `...` you get bad spacing, better use `\dots` instead

Comment: Your quotation marks are wrong, they are both closing. Use \`i' instead

Comment: Hard coding text like ` where we have used eq. (1)` will lead to errors if the numbering changes. In the spirit of latex, use ` \eqref{foo}` and add `\label`{foo}` inside the equation you want to reference.

Comment: Don't put whole words like `where` in math mode the kerning will be totally wrong

Comment: Don't add your math brackets like `[...]`, they won't resize with their content. For automatic resizing use `\left[...\right]` which works most of the time. For more control insert the correct sizes manually.

Comment: and finally: the text could make good use of a spell checker

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz can you make the following changes and show me what you meant as there are lot of comments and unable to digest them.Would love your support and effort.